# Java - I need to use a variable boolean inside the main method, initialized outside but within the same class

Tags: java, boolean, program-entry-point

The boolean has to be outside the main method so other methods can manipulate it. I've searched everywhere and cannot find a suitable answer because all I stumble upon are solutions for booleans as methods. It has to be a simple boolean and it cannot be static. Don't have much time, so any help would be great. Thanks.

```
public class myClass {

   private int[][] holdsStuff;
   private boolean isNeeded;

   public setFalse (){
   }

   public setTrue () {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //call methods to change isNeeded
      //require isNeeded to prevent invalid changes being made to holdsStuff
   }
}
```

Comment: declare in `main`, pass it to the other methods that need it. or make it `static` (*"it cannot be static"* smells like homework)

Comment: Also, you forgot the return types in your methods...

Comment: Don't do any changes to `holdsStuff` in `main`, only in methods.

Comment: Frederico, we all have to learn. Return types for both are (int, int).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use *isNeeded* in other methods and in *main* method which is *static* and *static* methods just deal with static data [read this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/211137/why-can-static-methods-only-use-static-data). so what you want to do is make instance of this class to call *isNeeded* in *main* method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       myClass myclass = new myClass();          
       boolean isNeeded = myclass.isNeeded;
   }
```

Comment: This is all I needed. I did try this but I obviously had my syntax wrong.

Comment: Show me what you got !!

Comment: I'm new to this site, I can only see options to add a comment (no code) or answer the question. I was on the right track, but when I created an instance of the class I did it for a constructor which took two integers as an argument for an array object. I thought I needed to create a new instance for the boolean, but the boolean value was changed by methods that manipulated the object. So my boolean value never turned true in main. As soon as I used it with the already created instance, everything worked as it should. A simple thing but it taught me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If class member `isNeeded` is not static, then it must belong to an instance of `myclass`, you can create a new instance and manipulate this instance:

```
public class myClass {

    private int[][] holdsStuff;
    private boolean isNeeded;

    public void setFalse (){
        isNeeded = false;
    }

    public void setTrue () {
        isNeeded = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myClass mc = new myClass();
        myClass.setFalse();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myClass {

       private int[][] holdsStuff;
       private boolean isNeeded;

       public void setFalse (){
       isNeeded =false;
       }

       public void setTrue () {
        isNeeded = true;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           myClass myclass = new myClass();
           myclass.setFalse();
           myclass.setTrue();
          //call methods to change isNeeded
          //require isNeeded to prevent invalid changes being made to holdsStuff
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

since main is static either use static keyward or make an instance of the same class. use static key the following:

```
public class myClass {

   private int[][] holdsStuff; // make this static if you are also this inside main
   private static boolean isNeeded;

   public static setFalse (){
   }

   public static setTrue () {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //call methods to change isNeeded
      //require isNeeded to prevent invalid changes being made to holdsStuff
   }
}
```